# Como generar dos numeros Randoms enteros en Java

Tags: java, random

Como puedo generar un numero random de caracter entero en java

a = Math.random() * 25 + 1;
 System.out.println(Math.round(a))
//el 25 pone el limite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El método [Random.nextInt(n)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)) proporciona lo necesario, podes usarlo de esta forma:

```
int aleatoreo(int vMin, vMax) {
   Random r = new Random();
   return vMin + r.nextInt(vMax - vMin + 1);
}

System.out.println(aleatorio(0,25));
```

Te generará un número pseudoaleatorio entre [`vMin`, `vMax`] o [`0`, `25`] en el ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Este metodo te puede ayudar;

```
public static int generarAleatorio(int min, int max){
    Random random = new Random();
    return random.nextInt(max-min+1)+min;
}
```

Siendo el primera parametro `min` el numero desde donde quieres iniciar y `max` el final.

Edito la respuesta segun los comentarios del autor:

```
package numeros_aleatorios_enteros;

import java.util.Random;


public class Numeros_aleatorios_enteros {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(generarAleatorio(1, 25));       

    }
    public static int generarAleatorio(int min, int max){
        Random random = new Random();
        return random.nextInt(max-min+1)+min;
}

}
```

Comment: Cambio Min y Max por los valores aleatorios que quiero generar por ejemplo public static int generarAleatorio(int min, int max){
    Random random = new Random();
    return random.nextInt(1-25+1)+min;
}

Comment: Me parece que estas aprendiendo, solo debes colocar esta función tal cual en tu main y mas abajo solo debes invocar la función generarAleatorio(1,25);

Comment: Imprimiendolos con un sout?

Comment: @Andree he modificado la respuesta, te he agregado el proyecto completo.

Answer (score 0):

Sólo quería señalar dos cosas, ya que convendría tener una función para hacer esta operación.

1. Si el valor `min` que le pases es mayor al valor `max`, vas a tener un crash en la aplicación, ya que se levantará la excepción `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bound must be greater than origin`. Entonces eso hay que evitarlo.
2. Después de Java 8, se agregó el [método `ints` a la clase `Random`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#ints--), con el cual se pueden generar los randoms de una forma más eficiente.

Pongo entonces una respuesta aplicando los dos puntos mencionados. En este caso, el valor retornado será `-1` cuando el valor de `min` sea mayor que el valor de `max`. Esto puede cambiarse, según el uso que se la vaya a dar al método.

### Código:

<kbd>**[VER DEMO EN REXTESTER](http://rextester.com/VDI34265)**</kbd>

```
import java.util.Random;

class Rextester
{  
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println(getRandomInRange(0, 25));        
        System.out.println(getRandomInRange(250, 25));        
        System.out.println(getRandomInRange(1, 25));        
        System.out.println(getRandomInRange(0, 88));        
        System.out.println(getRandomInRange(1, 88));        

        /*Prueba controlando si min es mayor que max*/

        int myRandom=getRandomInRange(50, 25);
        if (myRandom==-1){
            System.out.println("No se puedo generar un random");        
        }else{
            System.out.println("Random generado: "+myRandom); 
        }
    }

    /*Función que se podría incorporar a una clase utilitaria*/
    private static int getRandomInRange (int min, int max) {
        int rValue = -1;
        if (max>min) {
            Random r = new Random();
            rValue= r.ints(min, (max + 1)).limit(1).findFirst().getAsInt();
       }
        return rValue;
    }
}
```

#### Resultado:

```
17
-1
12
19
54
No se puedo generar un random
```